# python networkx- save disconnected graphs from single figure into separate files

Tags: python, python-2.7, networkx, digraphs

I have following program that generates my graph and displays it on a single figure.

> Edges2 = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (4, 5), (6, 7), (6,8)]
>
> G = nx.DiGraph()

The function that generates the graph is as follows:

```
    def create_graph(G,nodes,Sets):

G.add_edges_from(nodes)

#value assigned to each world
custom_labels={}
custom_node_sizes={}
node_colours=['y']

for i in range(0, len(Sets)):
    custom_labels[i+1] = Sets[i]
    custom_node_sizes[i+1] = 5000
    if i < len(Sets):
        node_colours.append('b')

 

nx.draw(G,labels=custom_labels,node_list = nodes,node_color=node_colours, node_size=custom_node_sizes.values())
#show with custom labels
plt.show()
```

To the above function I am passing the list of edges (Edges2).
The function generates two disconnected graphs on a single figure. However, I would like to save these two graphs separately.

**So basically, is there a way of saving two disconnected graphs into two files? So, I can get graph1.png and graph2.png.**

Comment: What do you send as an input 'Sets' to the function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not quite get the 'Sets' input to your function or why do you `add_edges_from(nodes)` you use nodes as input and not edges!. So to answer your question of plotting disconnected graphs in 2 separate files I reproduced the problem without the custom_labels as it depends on the 'Sets' input and I sent the Edges2 as an input for nodes and Sets as well. As suggested by @joel I used the `weakly_connected_component_subgraphs` function and then looped the output of the function save each graph separately. So in the end the original graph is saved in **original_graph.png** , the subgraphs are saved in **graph1.png** and **graph2.png** respectively.

```
def create_graph(G,nodes,Sets):
    G.add_edges_from(nodes)

    #value assigned to each world
    custom_labels={}
    custom_node_sizes={}
    node_colours=['y']

    for i in range(0, len(Sets)):
        custom_labels[i+1] = Sets[i]
        custom_node_sizes[i+1] = 5000
        if i < len(Sets):
            node_colours.append('b')
    nx.draw(G,node_list = nodes,node_color=node_colours, node_size=1000, with_labels = True)
    plt.savefig("original_graph.png")
    plt.show()
    G_comp = nx.weakly_connected_component_subgraphs(G)
    i =  1 
    for comp in G_comp:
        nx.draw(comp,node_color=node_colours,  node_size=1000, with_labels=True)
        #show with custom labels
        fig_name = "graph" + str(i) + ".png"
        plt.savefig(fig_name)
        plt.show()
        i += 1


Edges2 = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (4, 5), (6, 7), (6,8)]
G = nx.DiGraph()
create_graph(G,Edges2,Edges2)
```

**Original graph**
[image]

**graph1 and graph2**
[image]

EDITED BY AKI:
I have added the labels which I needed (see comments). The last part of the code is:

```
    i =  1
    custom_number = 1;
    for comp in G_comp:
        dictfilt = lambda x, y: dict([ (i,x[i]) for i in x if i in set(y) ])
        wanted_keys = (range(custom_number,custom_number + len(comp)))
        newdict = dictfilt(custom_labels, wanted_keys)

        nx.draw(comp,node_color=node_colours,  node_size=1000, with_labels=True, labels = newdict)
        #show with custom labels
        fig_name = "graph" + str(i) + ".png"
        plt.savefig(fig_name)
        plt.show()
        custom_number += len(comp)
        i += 1
```

This improved version picks up necessary data from dictionary.
Many thanks to @author of the answer

Comment: The sets list could be as follows: Sets2 = [[('or', 'r', 't')], [('not', 'r'), 'r'], [('not', 's'), 'r'], ['r'], [('box', 's')],[('box', 'b')],[('box', 'b')], [('box', 'c')]]

Comment: And in fact if I use my labels it doesn't give me the correct graphs, the graph2 gives me an error. Is there a way of allowing these custom labels to be present on both seperated graphs? My labels work fine with the original graph but with the splitted graphs error is present

Comment: I still do not get what does 'Sets' represent but in general if you want to display labels, you have to create a **labels** dictionary which maps each node to a label then nx.draw(G, labels = labels, with_labels=True)

Comment: The sets need to be displayed for each node. So rather placing 1, it needs to be [('or', 'r', 't')], it is important to display it rather than displaying numbers. When I did your suggested operation I am not getting the graph2 at all. I already have custom_labels={} can I reference it somehow so that each node correspond to one label in given order?

Comment: I  had troubles understanding how you create your custom_labels, for instance why do you custom_label[i+1] by this you are not giving a label to node 0 !

Comment: The problem is solved and I added it to your answer. I believe it could be quite useful for this topic, is there a way of adding actual arrows to my graphs including reflexive arrows?

Comment: Great, I do not know about arrows in networkx but if you write into a gexf file using `write_gexf(G,"graph.gexf")` you can then open it with **gephi** and do a lot of manipulations to the figure you have

Answer (score 0):

since your graph is **directed**,you need to extract **strongly connected components** of your graph:

```
graphs = nx.strongly_connected_component_subgraphs(G)
```

more details can be found [here](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.strongly_connected.strongly_connected_component_subgraphs.html#networkx.algorithms.components.strongly_connected.strongly_connected_component_subgraphs)
there are some other useful methods for components which you can find [here](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms.component.html)

Comment: `connected_component_subgraphs` doesn't give the **strongly** connected components, and in fact isn't written for directed graphs.  You meant `strongly_connected_component_subgraphs`.  **However** I think the OP actually wants weakly connected components: `weakly_connected_component_subgraphs`.  It would also help if your answer gave instructions for how to plot the components separately.

Comment: yeah you were right, I meant strongly connected comp but I added wrong code.Thanks ;)

Comment: I will test it later today, however if someone has written similar function that I need please share it :).

Comment: so for the input Edges2 = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (4, 5), (6, 7), (6,8)], I am using the following: graphs = list(nx.strongly_connected_component_subgraphs(G)) . My outcomes are: [<networkx.classes.digraph.DiGraph object at 0x1117a4190>, <networkx.classes.digraph.DiGraph object at 0x1117b7e10>, ... <networkx.classes.digraph.DiGraph object at 0x114c59110>]
I think something is wrong as I have 2 components and I am getting 8 of them...

Comment: Also how can I save each of them as a .png file?

Comment: @aki : so use weakly_conncted_component_subgraph method !
and Yes , you can save each of subgraph as a .png file.because as you see subgraph returns DiGraph object !